# Count the total and percentage of values in character class column

Tags: r, sum, character, percentage

In a large dataset I have a column (treatment) which contains numbers, sometimes more then one, but is classed as character.

```
treatment <- c("1", "1", "2", "5", "1,2", "2,5", "1,2,5", "3") 
df <- data.frame(treatment)
```

Each number represents a treatment.
I want to count the total number and percentage of each treatment.

Desired output:

```
treatment   number     percent
   1           4          50
   2           4          50
   3           1          12,5
   5           3          37,5
```

I've tried to sum and to use `group_by(treatment) %>% summarise(percent = 100 *n() / nrow(df)`
But i'm having trouble with the rows with multiple numbers and it's class character.
Any tips?

Comment: How are you getting 50% for treatments one and two? I am getting  4 / (4+4+1+3) = 0.33 or 33%?

Comment: Aha, i neglected to mention that each row represents a contact. The percentage of treatment is calculated over the total of rows (contact). So treatment 1 has a total number of 4, 4 / 8 (rows/contacts) should be 50 percent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tidy::separate_longer_delim` to separate out the combined values by `","` - i.e.:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

separate_longer_delim(df, treatment, ",")
#   treatment
#1          1
#2          1
#3          2
#4          5
#5          1
#6          2
#7          2
#8          5
#9          1
#10         2
#11         5
#12         3
```

Then simply use `dplyr::count()` to count and `dplyr::mutate` to get the percents. Note, since you mentioned each row is a contact, you can create a simple element to identify the number of contacts.

All together (and thanks to @DarrenTsai for the improved approach):

```
contacts <- length(df$treatment)

separate_longer_delim(df, treatment, ",") %>%
  count(treatment) %>%
  mutate(percent = n / contacts)
```

Output

```
  treatment n percent
1         1 4   0.500
2         2 4   0.500
3         3 1   0.125
4         5 3   0.375
```

Note, to get the same results with older versions of `tidyr` (<v1.3):

```
xx <- max(nchar(gsub(",", "", df$treatment)))
contacts <- length(df$treatment)

df %>%
  separate(treatment, into = paste0("col", seq_len(xx)), sep = ",") %>%
  pivot_longer(everything(), values_drop_na = TRUE, names_to = NULL, values_to = "treatment") %>%
  count(treatment) %>%
  mutate(percent = n / contacts)

#  treatment     n percent
#  <chr>     <int>   <dbl>
#1 1             4   0.5  
#2 2             4   0.5  
#3 3             1   0.125
#4 5             3   0.375
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm having some trouble finding the function separate_longer_delim. Im currently running the Tidyverse package (which includes tidyr 1.1.4), however it only finds the function separate / separate_rows.

Comment: Can you update your `tidy` package? `separate_longer_delim` is in v1.3

Comment: @RvS also see edit for how to use `separate` instead of the newer, `separate_longer_delim` (a bit more convolutes - see why the latter was created!)

Comment: It works! Thank you very much for your quick answers! God i love this platform!!